# ASPSessionID is changed intermittently between requests on IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, asp-classic, session-cookies, iis-10

We have a classic ASP site running on IIS 10 over https.
On some clients using IE 11, an authenticated user is redirected to login page randomly. It is random as in there is no specific page which causes this issue, and it happens intermittently.
Upon investigation, we have found out that ASPSessionID in the request cookie gets changed automatically when this happens, that's why it redirects to login page because the new ASPSessionID is not valid (may be).

For example:
A user logs in and reaches homepage: in network tab of developer tools I can view the cookie i-e ASPSessionIDXXXXXX: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
User keeps clicking different links and on each request, the same cookie is being sent to the server.
Then suddenly user clicks some link say pageA.asp and he is redirected to the login page.
If we look at the network tab in dev tools. we see a GET request for pageA.asp and a 302 response. The cookie value in the request header is not the same as of previous request like the name remains same ASPSESSIONIDXXXXXX but the value is ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ which is different.

It happens only on IE 11 and only for some clients.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the `Internet Settings` under the `Tools` menu check that `Always allow session cookies` is enabled in the `Privacy` tab under the `Advanced Privacy Settings` dialog.

Comment: Yes it is checked.

Comment: I suggest you find the difference between the IE 11 browser or windows OS which is working for some users and which is not working for others. check whether all machines are using the same update or not. All IE 11 browser has similar settings or not. if not make it similar and then test it. Try to reset IE 11 browser and check whether it fixes the issue or not. Also, try to check why ASPSessionID in the request cookie gets changed automatically. check whether it caused by IIS or your application. It may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT okay I will check for the differences between 'good' client and 'bad' client. But I am not able to locate the cookies on windows. I have tried everything, but cookies are nowhere to be found. I don't know if session cookies even reside on the OS filesystem as files, or are they stored in some database like sqllite or something. Secondly I can't seem to find a way to check how the ASPSessionID is being changed. Because all I can see is two subsequent GET requests in network tab of IE development tools, with one request having a cookie with one value and one with the different value

Comment: Please try to find the difference in the IE settings or OS updates.

Comment: @Bilal, Is the issue resolved or issue still persists? If the issue is resolved please share the solution for the issue. If the issue persists please inform us about the current status of the issue. We will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Issue has not been resolved. Actually the issue is only for a few clients so for now we have ignored it as it is. Currently working on something else, but we have to resolve it and I will certainly share the solution if found one, or ask for help here. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Let us know if any further help needed. We will try to provide possible suggestions.